# Firebase signInWithCredential failed: First argument "credential" must be a valid credential

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using the react-native-facebook-login package to log users in. Currently the flow is working well and after the user enters their details, I successfully see an object returned with their information.

When I try and create an account in Firebase with signInWithCredential, I receive the following error message:

```
signInWithCredential failed: First argument "credential" must be a valid
```

I can't seem to find a breakdown of how that credential needs to be passed - is it a string, an object, an array etc. Is it just the token or do I need to pass other details (i.e. the provider)?

The credentials object I am currently getting back has:

- permission: Array
- token: String
- tokenExpirationDate: String
- userId: String

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I experienced the same error while using FirebaseUI and eventually realized that the Firebase library version was a bit old (the patch part of the version). After update the error was gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feeling pretty pleased - finally cracked the nut.

They key bit is the token needs to be changed first before being a relevant credential. See code below:

```
onLogin={function(data){
    let token = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.credentials.token);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(token)
       .then((user) => {
           console.log(user)
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.error('User signin error', err);
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question, based on the documentation of firebase:
where GoogleAuthProvider could be any of your setup / supported auth providers

```
// Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);

// Sign in with credential from the Google user.
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

On a side note, as you are using react-native and firebase, did you already try [react-native-firestack](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack)? makes a lot of things easier.